# Firebase storage data showing twice

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Trying to load data in collection view with this method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if urls.count == 0 {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
    let url = urls[indexPath.item]
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier,
                                                  for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
    storageRef.reference(withPath: url).getData(maxSize: 15 * 1024 * 1024, completion:  { data, error in
            if let data = data {                   
                cell.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        })
    return cell
}
```

The thing is - at first i can see both cells without data, then completion get called, an i'm getting a data, but the first image in both cells.
How can i do it right? And how can i get metadata in the same time too?

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot:]

UPD:

I wrote an array

```
    var datas = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]
```

An changed cell code to

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier,
                                                  for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = datas[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}
```

And got this:

[image]

Still can't see what's wrong. My overrided methods:

```
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return datas.count / 2
}
```

Comment: can you add the screenshot as well ?

Comment: @TalhaQ i will, but i don't think it'll be usefull

Comment: @TalhaQ, as asked

Comment: I believe you need to use this storageRef.reference(withPath: url).getData outside collectionview scope.Save data in array and populate here

Comment: Run getting image from storage outside of your cellForItemAt in a function and all the images received in array and then use that respective array to show images in cell will solve your problem

Comment: @iOSGeek watch the end

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're downloading the information in the *cellForItemAt indexPath:* function and you should download the images in another function like this

```
//Variable to store the UIImages
    var images = [UIImage]()

//function to download the images, run it in the viewdidload like self.getImages()
    func getImages(){

        for url in self.urls{

            storageRef.reference(withPath: url).getData(maxSize: 15 * 1024 * 1024, completion:  { data, error in
                if let data = data {
                    self.images.append(UIImage(data: data))
                }
            })
        }

        self.YourCollectionView.reloadData()

    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if urls.count == 0 {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier,
                                                      for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
        cell.imageView.image = self.images[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Should return 1 in `numberOfSection` func

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```